# How to Get value from Infragistics combo

Tags: c#, javascript, combobox, client-side, infragistics

I am using Infragistics igCombo in my web form. I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 as a server side technology. I can easily bind data but can't get the value which user selects and sends to the server. I want to know how to get values from combo using server side API or using JavaScript API of Infragistics. Any other solution which is not provided by Infragistics will be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

For the client side, you can use code similar to the following:

```
value = igcmbo_getComboById(m_ComboId).getValue();
```

where m_ComboId is a javascript variable created on the server-side containing the control's ID:

```
"m_ComboId = '" + Combo.ID + "'"
```

For server-side access of the value, use the DataValue property of the combo.